# Unable to get Text on Bar Chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I quite new to D3 and I am stuck with Text Issue in d3.

Here is the D3 Code for a bar chart, I am simply unable to get text on the bars.
The code for text is at the bottom. I am also attaching the picture for the chart.

[image]

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

                    var margin = { top: 80, bottom: 80, right: 80, left: 80 },
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


                    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.bottom + ")");

                    d3.tsv("tickets.tsv", function (error, data) {
                        dataset = data.map(function (d) { return [d["ticket"], +d["num"]]; })

                        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data.map(function (d) { return [d.ticket]; }))
                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

                        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max([d.num]); })])
                .range([height, 0]);


                 var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.ticket); })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return yScale(d.num); })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yScale(d.num); })
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("fill", "orange");

                 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .orient("bottom");

                 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left");

                 svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0" + "," + (height) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

                 svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .call(yAxis);

                 var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("text");

                 var labels = text
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.ticket; })
                .attr("y", 400)
                .text(function (d) { return d.num; });

                 ;
                 });

                </script>   
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/)?

Comment: Any problems with the solution in the response?

Comment: I went through the tutorial, I think i am making some error

Comment: I used the below code                                                            rect.append("text")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.ticket); })
                .attr("y", 100)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function (d) { return d.num; });

Comment: Bear in mind that if you don't get the selection piece right, the text will not be displayed. The response below is addressing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are selecting based on text and there are already the tick text elements present...so, nothing to do off the `.enter()` selection. So, select the text based on a class that you specify. Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jSZ7E/) with the simple solution.

```
var text = svg.selectAll(".text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","text");
```

NOTE: I am using a javascript variable for the data but it is simple to adapt for you TSV data.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, You mean since there is a text element available for axis. I cannot simply selectAll("text") once again. I must create a text class in css and then use that in the code as you mentioned above.

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz That is exactly right. If you do this, the original code you posted will work. I have not changed anything besides using a javascript variable as the data input.

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz And to make sure we are on the same page here, note how the assignment to a CSS class is done **in the code**, as you can see in the response and in the fiddle I linked.

Comment: You are awesome thanks, I was stuck with this for long time, didnt understand why i could not selectAll everytime i wanted to manipulate or add text, now i know. and Thanks for your brilliant effort on FIDDLE, it helped me immensely.

Comment: YMW. very glad to hear it helped you.